# Initialzing and accessing members of a variadic class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm experimenting with variadic templates and would like to know if they can be used in order to generalze(?) class templates such as

```
template<typename T1, typename T2 , typename T4, typename T4>
struct Foo
{
    T1      &m_member1;
    T2      &m_member2;
    T3      &m_member3;
    T4      &m_member4;
};
```

Also, I'd like to be able to initialize all the members by chaining constructors. This is how far I've gotten:

```
template<typename... Types>
struct Foo;

template<typename T , typename... Types>
struct Foo<T, Types ...> : public Foo<Types ...>
{
    Foo( T member , Types ... others ) : m_member( member ) , Foo<Types ...>( others )
    {
    }

    T   m_member;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T>
{
    Foo( T member ) : m_member( member )
    {
    }

    T   m_member;
};
```

Where the goal is to create objects like so:

```
Foo<char,int,bool,float> f( 'a' , 42 , true , 1.234 );
```

The code fails to compile (gcc 4.5.3) with the error:

```
TestVariadicTemplates.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo<T, Types ...>::Foo(T, Types ...)’:
TestVariadicTemplates.cpp:15:83: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
TestVariadicTemplates.cpp:15:83: note:         ‘others’
TestVariadicTemplates.cpp:15: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

**Edit**

What would be the best way to reference the various members of `Foo`?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::tuple`?

Comment: @pmr Thanks. std::tuple does a marvelous job. C++x11 is amazing!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do what it says: Expand the variables that come from Parameter packs (variadic parameters) with `...`.

That is, instead of

```
Foo<Types ...>( others )
```

write

```
Foo<Types ...>( others... )
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you suggest that I do this. This is my first foray into variadic templates.

Comment: @Olumide : [Online demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/7a9e302e6ec73e49837878b28f65d4dc)

Comment: f.m_member let me access the first char. How do I access the other values?